# c++ nested linkedlist not allowing node initialization in the base class then program.exe fails with no error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, linked-list

I am new to C++, and am trying to wrap my head around memory allocation, pointers and etc.

I have a basic program that keeps failing not sure why. I am using similar techniques in a different binary tree implementation that I wrote and it works fine.

The base class is `LinkList`
Nested within `LinkList` is a class `node`
`node` should contain an object of the external class `circle' as the data member

In the push_back function I try to initialize a new node and then add the new object passed from main to the node data member circle;

## 1. Not able to initialize a new node object, as such: `node n = new node;`

`err:the default constructor of 'LinkList::node' cannot be referenced`

## 2. If I init the new node obj. as a pointer, as such: `node * n;`

`err: uninitialized local variable tmp used`

BUT
if I initialize the tmp variable with a NULL value, it doesn't allow me to set:
`tmp->c = ci;`

At this point I've tried messing around with copy constructors and operator= function. Are any of those the right method or is there some logical error here?

Disclaimer: This is a very simple implementation I'm trying to get working. Not worried about time complexity or efficiency here!

Can reference the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circle {
    double rad, xCen, yCen;
    friend class node;
public:
    Circle(int r, int x, int y) : rad(r), xCen(x), yCen(y) {}
    //Circle(const Circle& obj) {
    //  rad = obj.rad;
    //  xCen = obj.xCen;
    //  yCen = obj.yCen;
    //}
    double getArea() {
        return (3.14*(rad*rad));
    }
    double getPerimeter() {
        return (2 * (3.14*rad));
    }

    Circle& operator=(Circle& left) {
        Circle *c = NULL;
        c->rad = left.rad;
        c->xCen = left.xCen;
        c->yCen = left.yCen;

        return *c;
    }

    void setRad(double r) { rad = r; }
    void setxCen(double x) { xCen = x; }
    void setyCen(double y) { yCen = y; }

    double getRad() { return rad; }
    double getxCen() { return xCen; }
    double getyCen() { return yCen; }
};



class LinkList {


    class node {
    public:
        Circle c;
        node * next = NULL;
    };


    node* head;
    node* tail;
public:
    LinkList() {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        tmp = NULL;
    }


    void push_back(Circle& ci) {

        node * tmp;
        //tmp->c = ci;//

        //node n = new node;

        //node * tmp = new node; // doesnt let init.

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = tmp;
            tmp = tail;
        }

        //cout << head->c.getArea();
    }

    //void push_front(Circle& c) {
    //  node * tmp;
    //  tmp = NULL;
    //  tmp->c = c;
    //  tmp->next = NULL;

    //  if (head = NULL) {
    //      head = tmp;
    //      tail = tmp;
    //  }
    //  else {
    //      tmp->next = head;
    //      head = tmp;
    //  }
    //}

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, LinkList ll);
    //friend Circle& operator=(Circle& left, Circle& right);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, LinkList ll) {
    //LinkList::node * start;
    //start = ll.head;
    //cout << start->c.getArea();

    //while (start->next != NULL) {
    //  os << "area" << endl;
    //  os << "perimter" << endl;
    //  start = start->next;
    //}

    return os;
}


int main()
{
    LinkList obj;
    obj.push_back(Circle(10, 2, 3));
    //obj.push_front(Circle(5, 1, 1));
    //obj.push_back(Circle(4, 3, 5));
    //obj.Sort();
    //if (obj.Find(3, 5)) {
    //  obj.Delete(3, 5);
    //}
    cout << obj;
}
```

Comment: `node` doesn't have a default constructor because one of its data members,  `c`, doesn't have a default constructor. You can change the `Circle` class constructor to `Circle(int r = 0, int x = 0, int y = 0)` to make it act as a default constructor as well.

Comment: I made the change, i can init. the node obj. as `node *tmp = new node` .However when i write `tmp->c = ci` it fails. (with no error).

Comment: Because inside your assignment operator you do `Circle* c = NULL; c->rad = left.rad...` yet `c` is a NULL pointer, that means it doesn't point to an object. Dereferencing a null pointer gives undefined behavior. You don't need to use pointers at all in your `Circle` class. Just do `Circle c;` and change all `->` to `.`. While you're at it you can get rid of the assignment operator completely as the compiler-generated one does the same thing.

Comment: If the default constructor is set to `Circle(int r = 0, int x = 0, int y = 0)` then on every circle init. it overwrites the incoming values with 0. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: It doesn't overwrite the incoming values. If I do `Circle myCircle(1, 2, 3)` then the values passed in are `1`, `2`, and `3`. Only if I *don't* provide arguments (i.e `Circle myCircle;`) then the `0` values used to initialize the variables.

Comment: ok well then, im not sure. if i check `Circle& ci` that was passed to the function it has correct values assigned to it. But then when i assign ``tmp node` to equal to 'ci'  the values do not get copied over even the i am using operator=

Comment: How are you checking the values? If you do `node* tmp = new node; tmp->c = ci; cout << tmp->c.getPerimeter() << " " << tmp->c.getArea();` it should do the right thing.

Comment: im debugging right now, checked in the Circle operator= function to see if the values are getting set.                                                                           `  Circle c;
  
  cout << left.getRad() << endl;
  cout << left.getxCen() << endl;
  cout << left.getyCen() << endl;


  c.rad = left.rad;
  c.xCen = left.xCen;
  c.yCen = left.yCen;

  cout << c.getRad() << endl;
  cout << c.getxCen() << endl;
  cout << c.getyCen() << endl;

  return c;`                                                                        And the values seem like they are getting set.

Comment: Here's your code that I fixed up a bit. It's working fine. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9a414e8bd417632